# How to clear drawing only in canvas?

Tags: android, android-canvas

I am trying to develop one application. I want to clear the canvas now, I wrote coding for clear the screen. Its working..but one issues background image also cleared. I want to clear drawings only. How to clear drawings only ? Here I set background image dynamically.

```
package com.example.graphicsdraw;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.EmbossMaskFilter;
import android.graphics.MaskFilter;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Path;
import android.graphics.PorterDuff;
import android.graphics.PorterDuffXfermode;
import android.view.Display;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout.LayoutParams;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private Button Back, Next, Erase,clrScreen;
    int FlagSet = 0, ImageSet = 0;
    static int Flag = 0;
    MyView myview;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        myview = new MyView(this);
        RelativeLayout myLayout = new RelativeLayout(this);        
        myLayout.setLayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT)); 
        Back = new Button(this); 
        Back.setText("Back"); 
        Next = new Button(this);
        Next.setText("Next");
        Erase = new Button(this);
        Erase.setText("Eraser");
        clrScreen = new Button(this);
        clrScreen.setText("Clear");
        myLayout.addView(myview); 
        myLayout.addView(Back); 
        myLayout.addView(Next);
        myLayout.addView(Erase);
        myLayout.addView(clrScreen);
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(60, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT); 
        params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM); 
        params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT); 
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params2 = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(60, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT); 
        params2.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT); 
        params2.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM); 
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params3 = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(65, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT); 
        params3.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_HORIZONTAL); 
        params3.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM);
        Erase.setLayoutParams(params3); 
        Erase.bringToFront(); 
        Next.setLayoutParams(params2); 
        Next.bringToFront(); 
        Back.setLayoutParams(params); 
        Back.bringToFront(); 
        clrScreen.setLayoutParams(params3); 
        clrScreen.bringToFront(); 
        this.setContentView(myLayout);


        Back.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                Flag = Flag - 1;
                startActivity(i);
                finish();

            }
        });
        Next.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                Flag = Flag + 1;
                startActivity(i);
                finish();

            }
        });

        Erase.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                //mPaint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR));
                /*Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                Flag = Flag;
                startActivity(i);
                finish();*/
                mPaint = new Paint();
                mPaint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.SRC));
                mPaint.setColor(Color.BLUE);
                mPaint.setAntiAlias(true); 
            }
        });
        clrScreen.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
        {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) 
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                myview.Clear_Drawing();

            }


        });

        mPaint = new Paint();
        mPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
        mPaint.setDither(true);
        mPaint.setColor(Color.WHITE);//0xffffffff
        mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        mPaint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
        mPaint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
        mPaint.setStrokeWidth(10);
        mEmboss = new EmbossMaskFilter(new float[] { 1, 1, 1 }, 0.4f, 6, 3.5f);
        mPaint.setMaskFilter(mEmboss);
    }
    private Paint       mPaint;
    private MaskFilter  mEmboss;
    public  class MyView extends View 
    {
        MainActivity ma=new MainActivity();
        Bitmap  mBitmap = null;
        private Canvas  mCanvas;
        Path    mPath = null;
        private Paint   mBitmapPaint;
        Bitmap bmp;
        Display  display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
        int width = display.getWidth();
        public MyView(Context c) {
            super(c);
            switch(Flag)
            {
            case 0:
                bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.a);
                break;
            case 1:
                bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ic_launcher);
                break;
            case 2:
                bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.a);
                break;
            case 3:
                bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ic_launcher);
                break;
            case 4:
                bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.a);
                break;
            case 5:
                bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ic_launcher);
                break;
            case 6:
                bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.a);
                break;
            case 7:
                bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ic_launcher);
                break;
            case 8:
                bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.a);
                break;
            case 9:
                bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ic_launcher);
                break;
            case 10:
                bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.a);
                break;
            case 11:
                bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ic_launcher);
                break;
            case 12:
                bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.a);
                break;
            case 13:
                bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ic_launcher);
                break;
            case 14:
                bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.a);
                break;
            case 15:
                bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ic_launcher);
                break;
            case 16:
                bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.a);
                break;
            case 17:
                bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ic_launcher);
                break;
            case 18:
                bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.a);
                break;
            case 19:
                bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ic_launcher);
                break;
            case 20:
                bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.a);
                break;
            case 21:
                bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ic_launcher);
                break;
            case 22:
                bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.a);
                break;
            case 23:
                bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ic_launcher);
                break;
            case 24:
                bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.a);
                break;
            case 25:
                bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ic_launcher);
                break;
            case 26:
                bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.a);
                break;
            case 27:
                bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ic_launcher);
                break;
            case 28:
                bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.a);
                break;
            case 29:
                bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ic_launcher);
                break;
            case 30:
                bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.a);
                break;
            case 31:
                bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ic_launcher);
                break;
            case 32:
                bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.a);
                break;
            case 33:
                bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ic_launcher);
                break;
            case 34:
                bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.a);
                break;
            case 35:
                bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ic_launcher);
                break;
            case 36:
                bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.a);
                break;
            case 37:
                bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ic_launcher);
                break;
            case 38:
                bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.a);
                break;
            case 39:
                bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ic_launcher);
                break;
            case 40:
                bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.a);
                break;
            case 41:
                bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ic_launcher);
                break;
            case 42:
                bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.a);
                break;
            case 43:
                bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ic_launcher);
                break;
            case 44:
                bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.a);
                break;
            case 45:
                bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ic_launcher);
                break;
            case 46:
                bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.a);
                break;
            default:
                break;
            }
            //Display  display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
           // int width = display.getWidth();
            mBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bmp, width, 350, true);
            //mBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, 350, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
            mCanvas = new Canvas(mBitmap);
            mPath = new Path();
            mBitmapPaint = new Paint(Paint.DITHER_FLAG);
            mBitmapPaint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.SRC)) ;                 

        }     
        protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas)
        {
            canvas.drawColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
            canvas.drawBitmap(mBitmap, 0, 0, mBitmapPaint);
            canvas.drawPath(mPath, mPaint);
        }
        private float mX, mY;
        private static final float TOUCH_TOLERANCE = 4;
        private void touch_start(float x, float y) {
            mPath.reset();
            mPath.moveTo(x, y);
            mX = x;
            mY = y;
        }
        private void touch_move(float x, float y) {
            float dx = Math.abs(x - mX);
            float dy = Math.abs(y - mY);
            if (dx >= TOUCH_TOLERANCE || dy >= TOUCH_TOLERANCE) {
                mPath.quadTo(mX, mY, (x + mX)/2, (y + mY)/2);
                mX = x;
                mY = y;
            }
        }
        private void touch_up() {
            mPath.lineTo(mX, mY);
            mCanvas.drawPath(mPath, mPaint);
            mPath.reset();
        }
        public void Clear_Drawing()
        {
            //mBitmap = null;
            mPath = null;
            mBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, 350, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
            mPath = new Path();
        }
       public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
            float x = event.getX();
            float y = event.getY();
            switch (event.getAction()) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    touch_start(x, y);
                    invalidate();
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                    touch_move(x, y);
                    invalidate();
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    touch_up();
                    invalidate();
                    break;
            }
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Did one of the answers resolve your question?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of drawing directly onto your background, you should use `myview.setBackground()` for your background.  Continue using `Bitmap.createBitmap(width, 350, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888)` to create a blank bitmap for drawing on.

```
mBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bmp, width, 350, true);
setBackground(mBitmap);
mBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, 350, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
mCanvas = new Canvas(mBitmap);
```

Comment: By the way, you can use the % operator to replace your big switch statement.  The expression Flag % 2 will evaluate to 0 for even numbers and 1 for odd numbers, so then 0 and 1 are the only two cases you need to handle.

Answer (score 0):

It will definately clear the background image as it is the part of canvas what you should do is use a framelayout place background as the 1st child and create transparent canvas over it and change the background of that 1st child in the framelayout don't draw the image on the canvas

Create a layout under the transparent canvas and when user changes the background image change that image on the layout below not on the canvas,rest is just fine

Comment: of course you can as you are currently doing it just keep in mind the background that you want to preserve must not be on canvas but below it

Comment: how can do it???if u can just edit my code and give me....thanks in advance...@aashish

Answer (score 0):

It's like resetting your drawing tools and providing a new canvas to draw.

```
 mBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(mv.getWidth(),mv.getHeight() ,Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);      
 mCanvas = new Canvas(mBitmap);
 mPaint = new Paint();
 mPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
 mPaint.setDither(true);
 mPaint.setColor(0xFFFF0000);
 mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);                               
 mPaint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);       
 mPaint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
 mPaint.setStrokeWidth(0);
 mv.invalidate();// call invalidate to refresh the view's draw.
```